# Compiling two programs fails

Tags: c++

For an assignment I have written two programs. 
One for generating a file of random integers, the other for counting integers less than a specified threshold.
You can find the actual assignment texts below the code I've posted.

When compiling g++ generate.cpp -o generate, I get this error:

```
    z1755294@hopper:~/assign2$ g++ generate.cpp -o generate
generate.cpp: In function ‘bool writeRand(int, int, int, const char*)’:
generate.cpp:12:31: error: variable ‘std::ofstream fout’ has initializer but incomplete type
         ofstream fout ( fname );
```

When I compile g++ thresh.cpp -o thresh, I get this error:

```
    z1755294@hopper:~/assign2$ g++ thresh.cpp -o thresh
thresh.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
thresh.cpp:19:16: error: variable ‘std::ifstream fin’ has initializer but incomplete type
  ifstream fin( fname.c_str() );
```

Can anyone help me  fix my code to get it working?  Also I need to create a Makefile for my project since I have multiple executables?

Thanks so much...kinda stuck on what to do.

---

This is my code:

generate.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>  // re. atoi

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cerr;
using std::ifstream;
using std::ofstream;

bool writeRand ( const int ranSeed, const int maxVal, const int numVals, const char* fname )
{
        ofstream fout ( fname );
        if ( fout )
        {
                srand ( ranSeed );
                for ( int i=0; i < numVals; ++ i )
                        fout << rand () % (maxVal+1) << endl;
                fout.close ();
                return true;
        }
        //else
        return false;
}

int main ( int argc, char* argv [] )
{
        if (argc !=5 )
        {
                cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << "ranSeed maxVal numVals outFileName" << endl;
                return -1;
        }

        const int ranSeed = atoi(argv[1]);
        const int maxVal = atoi(argv[2]);
        const int numVals = atoi(argv[3]);
        const char* fname = argv[4];

        if ( ranSeed <= 0 || maxVal <= 0 || numVals <= 0 )
        {
                cerr << "Invalid negative or zero numbers on command line....Try again..." << endl;
                return -1;
        }

        if ( writeRand( ranSeed, maxVal, numVals, fname ) )
                cout << "ranSeed = " << ranSeed << ", maxVal = " << maxVal << ", numVals = " << numVals
                << "\nfame " << fname << " was created ok ..." << endl;
        else
                cout << "There was a problem creating file " << fname << " ..." << endl;
}
```

---

thresh.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> // re. atoi

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;
using std::ifstream;
using std::string;
using std::flush;

int main ()
{
        //prompt and take in the desired file name
        cout << "Enter name of file (for example randNums.txt): " << flush;
        string fname;
        getline( cin, fname );

        //then can open file
        ifstream fin( fname.c_str() );
        if( fin )
        {
                int max, count = 0, below = 0, val = 0;
                string line;
                while( true )
                {
                        cout << "Enter the threshold value: " << flush;
                        getline( cin,line );
                        max = atoi( line.c_str() );

                        if( max > 0 ) break;
                        cout << "Try again with value > 0 \n";
                }

                while( getline( fin, line) )
                {
                        val = atoi( line.c_str() );
                        ++count;

                        if( val < max ) ++below;
                }
                fin.close();

                cout << below << " of " << count << " values in file '"
                     << fname << "' are less than " << max << '\n';

                max = val+1; //last value (in file) + 1
                count = 0, below = 0;
                fin.open( fname.c_str() );
                while( getline( fin, line ) )
                {
                        int val = atoi( line.c_str() );
                        ++count;

                        if( val < max ) ++below;
                }

                fin.close();

                cout << below << " of " << count << " values in file '"
                     << fname << "' are less than " << max << '\n';

        }
        else
 cout << "There was an error opening file " << fname << '\n';


        cout << "Please 'Enter' to continue/exit..." << flush;
        cin.get();
        return 0;
}
```

---

**Assignments**

**generate**

Create a program called "generate" which generates a file of random integers.
This program takes four command line arguments. They are, in order

*A random number seed. This is an integer value explained below.
*A maximum value. The random values should be less than this maximum. This value is an integer.
*The number of values to be generated
*The name of an output file to store the values

If the command line arguments are not given, the program should give a brief message on proper usage and then exit. The integer values on the comand line should all be checked for negative values. If a negative value is given, the program should print an error message and exit.
Random number generation

The rand() function, found in  returns a random positive integer every time it is called.  The srand(int) function takes an integer called the random number seed which is used to initialize the random number generator. Subsequent calls to rand() produce a random sequence which is uniquely tied to its seed. Typically in a program, srand() is called once, while rand() is called multiple times.

A common technique for producing random numbers of a particular size is to use the remainder of divding rand() by the maximum upper bound.

**thresh**

Create a program called thresh which should ask the user for a file name and an integer threshold value. The program should then count the number of values in the file less than the threshold and report the results.

For example, 43 of 300 values in mydatafile are less than 17
This program should not use command line arguments. Rather, needed values should be obtained by prompting the user.

When asking for the threshold value, if the user inputs a negative value, the program should print an error and loop on the request until a proper value is obtained.

If the input file does not exist, an error message should be printed and the program should exit.

***Hints:***

Test your programs with small values that can be checked by hand. For example, create a file of 20 values less than 10.  A particularly good test of thresh is to use the last value of the data file as a threshold value. Then use the last value plus one as a threshold value.

**A Makefile is required as part of your submission.  If the project has multiple executables, you should have a default makefile rule to build all of the executables.  You should have a rule to clear out the project to a pristine state.  Your Makefile should use appropriate variables.

Comment: Your program can only have one main() function, you have two. Your error is telling you that.

Comment: You should not copy the assigment text verbatim, but describe concisely what you do and what is wrong.

Comment: You want two programs -- generate and thresh -- right? Then you need to run g++ twice, once for each program.

Comment: Look at the errors, then add the include files for the types you missed.

Comment: So I fixed it by putting an #include <fstream> and now both files compile fine.  How do I create a Makefile for both of my cpp files to generate executables?  Also for the first program generate.cpp, is supposed to generate a file with random numbers but I don't see any files under my directory.  How can I fix this???

Comment: I got makefile and my cpp files to compile but does anyone know how to run the executable file created (generate and thresh) so I can test to see if the program runs correctly?

Answer (score 1):

As @mrunion pointed out, you should replace

`g++ generate.cpp thresh.cpp`

with `g++ generate.cpp`

and  `g++ thresh.cpp`

By the way, if you do these back to back, you'll overwrite your executable.  An improvement would be:

`g++ generate.cpp -o generate`

and

`g++ thresh.cpp -o thresh`